How to work correctly with PatternSynonyms: either redundant or incomplete or an exception
Let's say I want to simplify my case analysis by grouping multiple patterns with DInt. PatternSynonyms extension is perfect for it. I use COMPLETE pragma to avoid the warning about incomplete case analysis and the code is:
{-# COMPLETE DInt #-}                                                                                                         
data D = D1 Int | D2 Int | D3 String deriving (Eq, Show)                                                                      
pattern DInt :: Int -> D                                                                                                      
pattern DInt t <- (dInt -> Just t)                                                                                            
dInt :: D -> Maybe Int                                                                                                        
dInt (D1 n) = Just n                                                                                                          
dInt (D2 n) = Just n                                                                                                          
dInt _      = Nothing                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                              
f1 :: D -> String                                                                                                             
f1 d =                                                                                                                        
  case d of                                                                                                                   
    D3 s   -> "str:" <> s                                                                                                     
    DInt n -> "num:" <> show n

It works OK, but if I write the case as:
case d of
  DInt n -> ...  -- without D3 branch !

Then it leads to runtime exception without compile time warning! And the missing of warning is the problem 1.
Then, I try this:
  case d of                                                                                                                   
    DInt n -> "num:" <> show n                                                                                                
    D3 s   -> "str:" <> s   -- WARNING

And it works fine, but I get a warning: "Pattern match is redundant", and this is the problem 2.
How can I fix/avoid these 2 problems? Maybe the synonym is written in the wrong way?
One obvious solution is to move the conversion to string to the synonym, but in the real app I have a situation when some of terms/branches cannot lead to meaningful values, so - Nothing is used.

With {-# COMPLETE DInt #-}, you are telling GHC that a case analysis covering all of the patterns in your pragma (just DInt) is complete.
So of course it no longer warns when you only match on DInt; the entire purpose of the COMPLETE pragma is to avoid spurious warnings about incomplete case analysis by telling the compiler which sets of patterns provide complete coverage. And of course if you provide a branch for DInt (which you said is a complete match) and then any further branches would be redundant, so the compiler will warn about those.
If your intention was that a complete set of patterns is DInt and D3, then your COMPLETE pragma should say that. Try {-# COMPLETE DInt, D3 #-}.
For more reading, see the relevant section of the GHC user's guide.
